# Retrieving user password from DB

Tags: c#, sql, visual-studio-2010

I have a table that has a list of user names and passwords and I want to match the the user name and password the user enter with the one saved in the DB. The code I am using  only retrieves the login information of the first record in the users table, how can I change that so the code would work for all user.

I am a beginners at VS and I am trying to learn the basics so later on I will be implementing more complex login page with encryption.. Thank you

```
 private void btnLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        SqlDataReader dr;

        cn.ConnectionString = "Server=;Database=;User Id=naljalid;Password=";
        cmd.Connection = cn;
        string username = tbxUserName.Text;
        cmd.CommandText = "SELECT UserPassword FROM tblLoginProject WHERE UserName=username";

        // open a connection to DB
        cn.Open();

        //read the table
        dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        //read a record from te data reader
         dr.Read();

        // compare the passwords


       if (tbxPassword.Text == dr.GetString(0))
         {
             MessageBox.Show("Hello");
        }

        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Login failed, please re-enter your password");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why would you want to load all the users if only one is logging in?  Just remove the WHERE clause, and store the results in a container somewhere in your app, if that is what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the query a tidge to this:

```
cmd.CommandText = "SELECT UserPassword FROM tblLoginProject WHERE UserName = @username";
```

and then set that parameter value:

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", tbxUserName.Text);
```

That will get you the row for the user you're looking for. Now on to a few more recommendations. The ADO.NET classes implement the `IDispoable` interface. That interface identifies that the class uses some unmanaged resources. You want to make sure those get disposed. Consider the following rewrite of your current code:

```
using (SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection("Server=;Database=;User Id=naljalid;Password="))
using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT UserName FROM tblLoginProject WHERE UserName = @username AND Password = @password", cn))
{
    cn.Open();

    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", tbxUserName.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", tbxPassword.Text);

    var result = cmd.ExecuteScalar() as string;
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(result))
    {
        // user was not found
    }
    else
    {
        // user was found
    }
}
```

It leverages the `using` statement to ensure that the objects get disposed.

Answer (score 2):

The key to this is the SQL query, specifically the WHERE clause:

```
SELECT UserPassword FROM tblLoginProject
```

This query will return all the passwords from the database. But you want to retrieve the password of only one user, so you need to implement a WHERE clause

```
SELECT UserPassword FROM tblLoginProject WHERE UserName = @username
```

This query will retrieve the password for only a certain user where the value of the field UserName equals the value passed in the parameter @username. So now we need to make sure to pass that value. You *can't* just include it in the SQL query like you're doing right now. We do it like this:

```
cmd.Paramateres.AddWithValue("@username", username);
```

This should work fine, but for best practices you should check for both username *and* password at the same time:

```
SELECT count(*) FROM tblLoginProject WHERE UserName = @username AND UserPassword = @password
```

Then of course we pass both values:

```
cmd.Paramateres.AddWithValue("@username", username);
cmd.Paramateres.AddWithValue("@password", password);
```

This will return 0 if no users are found with that combination of username and password (invalid login), or more than 0 if such a user was found (valid login).

Next stop you should research hashing passwords. After that would be salting these hashes. Good luck!